# Liferay and Content-Security-Policy

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, content-security-policy

Does Liferay 6.2 provide any support for setting `Content-Security-Policy` response headers through configuration?

I do not want to add an (admittedly simple) `ServletFilter` if the support is already there.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

portal doesn't support CSP because it contains inline JavaScript and I believe also JS templates that evaluate during runtime.